# How to change textbox background color to red using button and event listener

Tags: html, event-listener

This is what i've tried.

If I try to use onclick inline js it works but I want to make it work using event listener

```js
function fnameCheck(){
    var fname = document.getElementById('fname');

    if(fname=""){
        alert('Please enter first name');
        document.querySelector('#fname').style.backgroundColor = "red";
        return false;
    }
    
    if(fname.length<=2){
        alert('First name cannot be less than 2 character!');
        document.querySelector('#fname').style.backgroundColor = "red";
        return false;
    }
}

document.getElementById('fnameBtn').addEventListener("click",fnameCheck);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it solve your query

I just added value attribute to
**var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="" id="fname">
    <button id="fnameBtn">Check</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fnameCheck(){
                var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
                console.log(fname);
                if(fname == ""){
                    alert('Please enter first name');
                    document.querySelector('#fname').style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    return false;
                }
                else if(fname.length <= 2){
                    console.log(fname.length);
                    alert('First name cannot be less than 2 character!');
                    document.querySelector('#fname').style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    return false;
                }else {
                    alert('Fname is satisfied');
                    document.querySelector('#fname').style.backgroundColor = "green";
                    return false;
                }
            }
document.getElementById('fnameBtn').addEventListener("click",fnameCheck);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works but only for a split second then it disappear again